# Rendering GridView inside ListView being slow

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` with various types of elements. Those elements are retrieved from an API, so they are dynamic. One of the possible elements is a photo gallery where photos must be displayed in pairs. I'm rendering this element using a two columns `GridView`. In other words: one of the possible `ListView` elements is a `GridView`. I know isn't a good practise to embed one `ScrollView` inside another one, but it's the best approach I've found.

There’s a problem with the `ListView` rendering, when it reaches the `GridView`, it freezes because it **inflates all the elements** inside the `GridView` regardless which are really going to be shown in the UI. I mean, if the `GridView` contains 200 elements, it inflates all of them. I don’t know how to make the `GridView` respect the common pattern of Android `GroupViews`, just inflate the displayed elements on screen in each particular moment.

Comment: do not do that. Both gridview and listview scroll and its like having scrollview withing scrollview.

Comment: I know, the gridview's scrolling is disabled to avoid problems

Comment: If you've disabled the GridView's scrolling, I wouldn't think you need the GridView then. Couldn't you just implement the ListView's adapter to display the paired image list item views where needed, instead of the GridView?

Comment: Yes, that could be a valid solution. I tried with the GridView before because the gallery has a complex logic, so I tried to isolated it in another widget